# ngx-gallery only showing medium size images

Tags: angularjs, gallery, image-gallery

I´ve build an image gallery using angular ngx-gallery. I cant get the responsive to work since the small and big images doesnt show. It only displays the medium 
 size images.

Here is how I implemented it:

These are the options:

```
this.galleryOptions = [
        {
            width: '100%',
            height: '254px',
            imageAutoPlay: true,
            imageAutoPlayPauseOnHover: true,
            imageSize: NgxGalleryImageSize.Contain,
            imageAnimation: NgxGalleryAnimation.Slide,
            thumbnails: false,
            preview: false
        },
        // max-width 544
        {
            breakpoint: 544,
            width: '100%',
            height: '250px',
            imageSwipe: true,
            imageArrowsAutoHide:true,
            imageAutoPlay: true,
            imageAutoPlayPauseOnHover: true,
            imageSize: NgxGalleryImageSize.Cover,
            imageAnimation: NgxGalleryAnimation.Slide,
            thumbnails: false,
            preview: false
        }
    ];
```

This is the array of images: (all url checked)

```
    this.galleryImages = [
        {
            small: 'assets/images/BannersResponsive/culturizate.jpg',
            medium: 'assets/images/Banners/radio_online_venezuela_fondo_demananacontigo.png',
            big: 'assets/images/BannersResponsive/culturizate.jpg'
        },
        {
            small: 'assets/images/BannersResponsive/culturizate.jpg',
            medium: 'assets/images/Banners/radio_online_venezuela_fondo_conexionyreflexion.png',
            big: 'assets/images/Banners/radio_online_venezuela_fondo_conexionyreflexion.png'
        }, ];
```

and this is the html:

```
<ngx-gallery class="gallery"                        
  [options]="galleryOptions                         
  [images]="galleryImages"></ngx-gallery>
```

I also tried naming the images the same and putting small,medium and big at the end of the name.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have the same issue but only in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I have had in my css:

`.mat-sidenav-container, .mat-sidenav-content, .mat-tab-body-content {
    transform: none !important;
}`

After I removed it everything works fine in all sizes.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for posting. In your component css?

Comment: In my case it is in the global css file, but I guess it could be in component css too.